# Template template parameter in C++ for class definition

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I would like to do be able to do something like this:

```cpp
template <...>
class A
{
   B<c> val;
   c test;
};

A<std::vector<int> > test;
```

So that I can reuse a my template template parameter in the `A` class.

Is this possible?

I have managed to get it working using template specification like this:

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class A 
{

};

template<template<typename > class B, typename C>
class A<B<C> >
{
    B<C> vec;
    C val;
};

A<std::vector<int> > a;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: The only better way is not even define the base template, just declare it: `template<typename T> class A;`. And define only a specialization. This is a fairly common approach, and there's absolutely nothing wrong with that, whatsoever. In any case, "better" is an eye of the beholder, and is mostly opinion, as such this is asking for opinions. Another option would be to just declare a regular template, and use `typename T::value_type` to define the `test` member.

Comment: You’re right, by better I meant to ask if there was a specific syntax that would allow not to declare a template specialization. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to extract the inner type is to use the following typetrait

```
template <typename T> struct inner_param;

template <template <typename, typename...> class C, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct inner_param<C<T, Ts...>>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

And then just:

```
using IntVector = vector<int>;
inner_param< IntVector >::type a;
a = 42;
cout<< a << endl;
```